# Mystery: Water vanished from flooded basement with no floor drain

Tags: basement, floor, drain, drainage, flooding

I live on a century old home whose unfinished basement got flooded this week. We had heavy rainfall which overwhelmed the city's storm sewer.

At a certain point there were about two inches of water on the basement floor so I left the house to buy a pump and hose ( we have no visible floor drain )

By the time I got back most of the water had gone. Any ideas of what may have sucked the water out in the absence of a floor drain? As far as I can tell I dont have a sump pump either.

Comment: A horde of thirsty rats?  :-)  How did the water get in?  Most of it could go out the same way.

Comment: Lol. The water started getting in near drain pipes that go directly into the concrete floor. At the worst point it seemed to be coming from the bottom of the foundation walls too.

Comment: I guess concrete is porous so the water could have gone through it just like it came in but I was surprised by how quickly it all went away ( a couple of hours ).

Comment: Concrete is porous, but not that porous.  There are likely gaps.  Doorway?  Sump pump?  Floor drains or openings (outlet hole for condensate, poorly sealed pipe openings)?  You wouldn't normally get several inches of standing water unless it has an easy path in.

Comment: The openings fixer mentioned, along with the joint at the entire perimeter of the slab.

Comment: Do you know what a french drain is? Perhaps you have one.

Comment: If you really have to know, you could pour some coloured water in about the same place and follow it wherever it goes... I'd guess there's a drain hidden somewhere, or a leak/crack in the sewer that let the water in during the storm

Comment: Examine the wall-floor joint, that's where the water came from (without a floor drain), and that's where it got out. I am surprised that the water receded such fast, guess your floor has pulled away from the wall and left a relatively wide vertical crack. Your foundation seems sitting on sandy soil, so the water comes and leaves freely.

Answer (score 2):

The water left through cracks, joints, or other openings in the concrete when the groundwater level dropped below the basement floor level.

Comment: ...which is the same way it came in.